# Macro for setting Concatenate formula to entire column?

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a VBA code that I can use for a button that I want to have that runs the Concatenate formula to the entire column going down. So the formula I have for the first cell is '=CONCATENATE($F$4,$H$4,$J$4)'. I want the button to add Concatenate to the first row (row 4) and all the rows after that inside the "AS" column...

I tried recording a macro changing the formula of the cell to CONCATENATE and inputting the values but it does not seem to work when applying it to my button.

I am fairly new to VBA coding with formulas so I am sure there is a very simple way to do this. Sorry in advance if I do not understand some of the basics of your explanation :)

CURRENT CODE:

```
Private Sub ParetoButton_Click()


Range("AS3").Formula = "=CONCATENATE(F3,"" "", H3,"" "",J3)"


Range("AS").FillDown

End Sub
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Comment: Your recorded macro probably makes use of `Range.FillDown`. How does it "not seem to work", specifically?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon adding ```Range.FillDown``` gives me an error on the Range.

Comment: Yes, `Range` in `Range.FillDown` is an object, exactly like `Range.Formula` in the line just above it. That would be something like `Range("AS" & ActiveCell.Row).FillDown`, with a `Destination` parameter.

Comment: You need to make the references relative not absolute. And remove the `On Error resume Next` it hides errors that should be dealt with not skipped

Comment: I realize that the references need to be relative, which is what I don't know how to go about doing for this example

Comment: That's the dollar signs in the cell references in the formula. `$3` will be referring to row 3 for every single filled-down formula (i.e. at row 4, concatenates cells from row 3; at row 47, still concatenates cells from row 3; at row 4783, *still* concatenates cells from row 3), so you want `3`, not `$3`.

Comment: Alright, I fixed up the code a bit. But how do I have FillDown without having a set last row? I want it to FillDown the entire column based on the last row that has values in the concatenated cells...

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution after more research and playing around w/ other codes...

```
Private Sub ParetoButton_Click()


Range("AS3").Formula = "=CONCATENATE(F3,"" "", H3,"" "",J3)"


Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Range("AS3:AS" & LastRow).FillDown

End Sub
```

Comment: just an FYI find the last row first and then apply the formula to the whole range:  `Range("AS3:AS" & LastRow).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(F3,"" "", H3,"" "",J3)"` and you can skip the fill down.  This will act like fill down without the added code.